# How to maintain hash value even if order of column changes while calculating hash

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, hash

When we change the order of columns while finding hash its result is changing .Is there a way we can maintain this value even when order of column changes. We are using CDC in pysaprk using hash value . This is just an example with 2 columns. In actual we have 50-60 columns on which we need to check if any changed has happened

```
import oracledb
from pyspark.sql import Row
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType


class JobBase(object):
    spark=None
    arr_list=['curr_col1','curr_col2']
    arr_list2=['curr_col2','curr_col1']
    Oracle_Username=None
    Oracle_Password=None
    Oracle_jdbc_url=None
    firmographic_cdc_dataframe =None
    winner_org_calculations_attributes=['curr_col2','curr_col3','curr_col4','curr_col45']
    
    
    def __start_spark_glue_context(self):
        conf = SparkConf().setAppName("python_thread")
        self.sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
        self.glueContext = GlueContext(self.sc)
        self.spark = self.glueContext.spark_session

    def execute(self):
        self.__start_spark_glue_context()
        new_dict={}
        print('hello')
        schema = StructType([ \
        StructField("curr_col1",StringType(),True), \
        StructField("curr_col2",StringType(),True), \
        ])
        d = [{"curr_col1": '75757', "curr_col2": "fgsjdfd"}]
        # columnarray = array(self.arr_list)
        columnarray = array(self.arr_list2)
        # ,"curr_col3": 79,"curr_col4": 'pb',"curr_col45": "a","E_N": "b"
        df = self.spark.createDataFrame(data=d,schema=schema)
        df=df.withColumn("hash_value", sha2(concat_ws("||", columnarray), 256))
        #df = self.spark.createDataFrame(d)
        df.show()
  
        
def main():
    job = JobBase()
    job.execute() 
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
result of   df=df.withColumn("hash_value", sha2(concat_ws("||", columnarray), 256))
when columnarray=['curr_col1','curr_col2']
+---------+---------+--------------------+
|curr_col1|curr_col2|          hash_value|
+---------+---------+--------------------+
|    75757|  fgsjdfd|3162cb81bf242c4d9...|
+---------+---------+--------------------+

when columnarray=['curr_col2','curr_col1']

+---------+---------+--------------------+
|curr_col1|curr_col2|          hash_value|
+---------+---------+--------------------+
|    75757|  fgsjdfd|1528bbcb98b92a2ba...|
+---------+---------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Why not just sort `columnarray` before passing it to `sha2`? `sha2(concat_ws("||", sorted(columnarray))`

Comment: Good option. let me try